# Rails how to make sure my AJAX works when using an id that's not yet there

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a `current_order` that is set up in the application controller like this:

```
def current_order
  if user_signed_in?
    current_order = Order.where(customer_id: current_user.id, status: :open).first_or_initialize(status: :open)
  else
    current_order = Order.where(customer_id: guest_user.id).first_or_initialize(status: :open)
  end
end
```

The problem I have is that when adding an `order_item` to the `order` for the first time, the order's `id` is still undefined.

How can I make sure that the AJAX does work when I make my first `order_item`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `Order.id` the order must be saved first. Instead of [**`first_or_initialize`**](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_initialize) you can make use of [**`first_or_create`**](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create)

```
def current_order
  if user_signed_in?
    Order.where(customer_id: current_user.id, status: :open).first_or_create
  else
    Order.where(customer_id: guest_user.id, status: :open).first_or_create
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Will this lead to a problem with guest users leaving unused orders in the database. I think I'd rather not have this. So when his or her session is over?

Comment: It depends on whether you want to track the order or not. If you don't you may delete the orders after few days with a rake task or something

Comment: This is what I was thinking. All orders with status `open` should be deleted after three days. Should do it I suppose. Rake task you said? I'll look into it anyway. Thanks again.